# Make a dataframe of all unique words with their count and

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` like this

```
id `  text                             c1      
1     Hello world how are you people    1 
2     Hello people I am fine  people    1
3     Good Morning people               -1
4     Good Evening                      -1
```

I want to make `df2` such that, it contain all the words of `df1`only once with their count (total occurrence) **and**

I want to sum `c1` column and make a new column of it in `df2` (sum only if a word is in that row).

Expected output:

```
Word      Totalcount     Points  

hello        2             2             
world        1             1              
how          1             1              
are          1             1              
you          1             1              
people       3             1              
I            1             1             
am           1             1              
fine         1             1             
Good         2             -2            
Morning      1             -1            
Evening      1             -1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First extract column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html),[`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with counts and `sum`:

```
s = (df.pop('text')
       .str.split(expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(1, drop=True)
       .rename('text'))

df1 = (df.join(s)
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .drop_duplicates(['id','text'])
         .groupby('text', sort=False)['c1']
         .agg([('Totalcount','size'),('Points','sum')])
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'text':'Word'}))

print (df1)
       Word  Totalcount  Points
0     Hello           2       2
1     world           1       1
2       how           1       1
3       are           1       1
4       you           1       1
5    people           3       1
6         I           1       1
7        am           1       1
8      fine           1       1
9      Good           2      -2
10  Morning           1      -1
11  Evening           1      -1
```

EDIT:

For better performance use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
from itertools import chain

splitted = [x.split() for x in df['text']]
lens = [len(x) for x in splitted]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Word' : list(chain.from_iterable(splitted)), 
    'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(lens),
    'c1' : df['c1'].values.repeat(lens)
})

df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['id','Word'])
         .groupby('Word', sort=False)['c1']
         .agg([('Totalcount','size'),('Points','sum')])
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
       Word  Totalcount  Points
0     Hello           2       2
1     world           1       1
2       how           1       1
3       are           1       1
4       you           1       1
5    people           3       1
6         I           1       1
7        am           1       1
8      fine           1       1
9      Good           2      -2
10  Morning           1      -1
11  Evening           1      -1
```

Comment: Hey. I have millions of rows and 16gb ram. I am running out of memory when running `s=(df.op...` line. Is there any solution, that do not consume less memory while calculating the df?

Comment: @johndoe - Edited answer, please check it.